# Average of running count in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to find out the average of running count by having a calculated field for a particular year (in the filter). Sample of the data looks like below and I am trying to calculate the turnover rate which is no of customers left divided by average no of customers existing in that year.

And average no of customers = (#customers in jan + feb+...... + #customers in dec)/12

Customer ID Date of acquisition Customer attrition date
A01 1/2/2010
A02 1/2/2010
A03 2/2/2010    8/7/2010
B01 2/2/2010
B02 2/2/2010
B03 3/2/2010    8/1/2010
B04 3/2/2010
B05 4/2/2010    2/2/2011
B06 5/2/2010
B07 10/2/2010
B08 11/2/2010
B09 12/2/2010   3/4/2011
B10 1/2/2011
B11 1/2/2011
B12 2/2/2011
B13 2/2/2011
B14 3/2/2011
B15 4/2/2011
B16 4/2/2011

I am using this formula window_avg(running_count(countd)). however , its not working for me. I just want to have a single no for that particular year and should be able to toggle it by having year in filter.

for this, I am trying to have a calculated field which could resolve it. But I am not able to get it.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated